# What is an alternate way to Switch Off mobile without use of Power Button?

Tags: power-on

> Device : MMX A89
>  OS : ICS 4.0.4

What is an alternate way to Switch Off mobile without use of Power Button? Can we Switch Off from OS itself? Is there any setting available? Or Does it require to install any further app?

Comment: Related: [What is the fastest way to shutdown unrooted Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215782/218526)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some apps who have this feature, Like switch off, reboot and etc.

One of them is  [Notification Toggler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.notificationToggle&hl=en)  , This app isnt particularly for switch off and reboot stuff, but you can do that also. :)

EDIT::

I think you have to root your device to use reboot and shutdown ,  You can't do it without Root unless applications are signed with the System Firmware Key. And playstore applications aren't that kind of applications that are signed with that.

EDIT 2:

To root your Device , 
Check out these links,

[Link 1](http://www.andro-park.org/root-micromax-a89-easily/)

[Link 2](http://gizmophiliacs.com/2013/02/how-to-root-micromax-a89-ninja/)

[Link 3](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2140357)

Comment: I found a `- Shutdown & Reboot (requires root)` in `Available toggles & shortcuts:`. So I didn't have `Rooted` device :(

Comment: see edited answer

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Now how to deal with rooting process?

Comment: Added links in the answer for you mmx device

Answer (score 1):

There are few methods which you help you in restarting if your Android device power button is not working:

Have a luck trying this Option If your Android device is OFF

1) Connect your smartphone phone with charger and wait for few seconds.

2) Try Hard Resetting Using Home & Volume button.

If your smartphone is on then you just install "Power Button to Volume Button" or "Oneclick reboot" app from play store and have fun using your phone.

Source : http://www.indabaa.com/how-to-restart-android-phone-without-using-power-button/

**Disclosure**: I'm the author of the linked article.

Answer (score 1):

BEST POWER OFF Android App = "Menu Button App" - NO ROOT - NO Physical Button needed, Complete Power off

As of now the "Menu Button App" is the only one that I have found on Google Play that will actually and completely power off your android without touching a physical button, NO ROOT needed. Most apps just turn off the screen, they don't power off the droid.

1. Open the app.
2. Tap "BUTTON tab"
3. Tick "POWER DIALOG"
4. Touch "DISPLAY"
5. The round "Power Button" will display on screen.
6. Touch the "Power Button", then select "Power off or Restart"

If you find another app that does it better please let us all know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An alternate way to switch off your mobile phone completely, would be to toss it in the ocean and don't look back. Just joking!

Actually turning the phone off or restarting it is done through the OS itself, just like every OS of today. So one way of doing this would be to access the terminal (only if your phone is rooted) and issue the linux shutdown command since android is based on linux.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Now how to deal with rooting process?

Comment: @NullVoid that's a different question you should ask separately. Before doing so, take a look at [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575)

Answer (score 0):

YEah there is 
Try Connecting the charger
And then Hit The reset Button 
And Remove the charger 
Worked FOr Xperia C

Comment: Most if not all modern phones don't have a reset hole like older Xperias do, mind you.

Answer (score 0):

to power down Use "menu button" app from Google play.
No Root required