# How do I prevent people from shutting down my samsung phone?

Tags: samsung, power-on, power-options

When I have the passcode enabled, you can still shut down my phone when you press the power button. Is there any way to prevent people from shutting down my phone?

Comment: There is a way, but I'd like to know which phone model and Android version

Comment: I have a Samsung galaxy phone in the J series. The android version is 6.0.1(Marshmallow).

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it 100%, because it is, like mentioned by bmdixon and in here 
[How to prevent someone from powering off an android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65246/how-to-prevent-someone-from-powering-off-an-android-device), a hard-wired feature. But you can get rid of the on-screen-option with this App: [Smart Lockscreen protector (Play Store)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nezdroid.lockscreenprotector)