# How does a soft reset of a smartphone with Android really work?

Tags: shutdown, force-stop, soft-reboot

Does it only trigger some kind of "shutdown -h now"? Or are there any hardware mechanisms involved?

I want to know, what happens, if I shutdown the smartphone such as you can do with holding the "start" button for 10 to 20 seconds in most cases.

More concrete: What happens, if I press the power button on my Huawei P20 for 10 seconds? What steps are taken exactly?

Comment: Related answer on different question: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/82857/44325

Comment: See my answer to [How to perform a hot reboot using the terminal emulator?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219822/how-to-perform-a-hot-reboot-using-the-terminal-emulator). Related: [What is the fastest way to shutdown unrooted Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215782/218526)

Comment: The forced reboot by holding the power button for 10-20 seconds is AFAIK implemented in hardware. It directly resets the CPU. Therefore this forced reboot works even if all the software has crashed the the CPU is in an invalid state.