# How do I restart my phone without using my power button?

Tags: reboot

Recently my Huawei P8 Lite decided that it doesn't want to play videos in apps anymore. Videos that I tap on on Twitter, Youtube, Youtube Go, and Reddit just load infinitely and don't do anything. Videos in my browser work completely fine, however, and videos that I've recorded myself play just fine, and there's audio, but the screen stays black.

I've tried clearing caches and deleting/re-downloading apps, but nothing seems to work. The only thing I can think of is to reboot my phone. The problem is that my power button is broken, so I have no way of turning it off. My phone doesn't have a Home button, and my volume buttons aren't separate so I can't press them both at once. So I don't think a lot of those fixes are going to work for me.

Do I have any other options? I've seen people recommending apps that will reset my phone for me, but that usually means rooting my phone, and the ones that don't require rooting don't work. I'm not rooting my phone, so those options are out the window.

Is there anything else I can do? I just want my videos to work again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically power on Android when the charger is connected](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20021/automatically-power-on-android-when-the-charger-is-connected)

Comment: [What is the fastest way to shutdown Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215782/218526)

Comment: extract [platform-tools-latest-windows.zip](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-releases-separate-adb-and-fastboot-binary-downloads), enable usb-debugging, connect usb cable, open *C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe* as Administrator, `cd` into *platform-tools* folder, type `adb.exe reboot` (however, you should more care about what happens if battery is drained completely, see first link)

Comment: That did it - thank you!

Comment: No need to install the entire platform tools for that, see [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](/q/42474/16575)

Comment: @AdamMcKay please mark Robert's answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities:

## Reboot via ADB

1. Enable Developer options on your device and enable Android Debug Bridge (ADB).
2. Install the Android SDK or at least the minimal ADB environment on your PC.
3. Now connect your phone via USB to your computer
4. Execute `adb reboot`

## Reboot via app (requires root)

Rebooting your phone from within an app requires root permission. If your device is already rooted you can use one of the [reboot apps from PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=reboot&c=apps):