# How do I force a hard shutdown of a phone with non removable battery?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s7, hard-reset, shutdown

My phone is Samsung Galaxy S7 with Android 8, and any phone specific answers are welcome but I am looking for a general solution

A few days ago  my phone screen went crazy and started detecting touch events all over the place when it was just left alone on a table. The home button seemed to be unaffected and brought the phone to the home screen, but it didn't stay there long enough for me to be able to do anything. Long pressing the power button brought up the (power off, restart, emergency mode) interface, but it turns out touching anywhere on the screen other than the three specific buttons causes the buttons to disappear, and since touch events were getting auto generated, the shutdown option kept disappearing. Eventually I managed to stay on the shutdown interface long enough to press the shutdown button.

Is there any way to forcefully cause a hard shutdown on a phone that does not have a removable battery? I am looking for a general solution that works on all phones, if such a thing is possible. I would also like to know if this is possible from adb on an unrooted phone.

Comment: If u have USB Debugging enabled, you can use ADB to reboot or shutdown

Comment: Pressing the power button until the device reboots is the common way. Depending on the Android device you have to hold the power button for 10-60 seconds before the device reboots (hard reboot, no shutdown just a reboot).

Comment: @Robert worked on a samsung galaxy win (Android 4.something), didn't work on a samsung galaxy 6 (android 6)

Comment: @Robert also, would it work it there were constant touch events being detected on the screen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the fastest way to shutdown unrooted Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/215736/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-shutdown-unrooted-android-phone)

Comment: Related: [How to perform a hot reboot using the terminal emulator?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219876/218526)

Comment: Yes this works because it is AFAIK not implemented software but in hardware. No matter in what state the OS is pressing the power button for a long time reboots the device. Even if the OS has totally crashed or is in an invalid state.